# Python separate dictionaries for each input

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Currently my function adds each employee input into one dictionary, but I want to make it so each employee is its OWN dictionary. Then I will add all those dictionaries into the global dictionary. I'm completely stuck, so anything helps!

```
#Function for adding employee information
def add_emp():
    #Ask the user to add an employee
    print("Enter the employee's information:\n")
    #Input first and last name
    name = input("What is the employee's name? ").lower()
    #Input employee position
    position = input("What is their position? ").lower()
    #Input employee department
    em_department = input("What is their department? ").lower()
    #Input employee salary
    salary = float(input("What is their salary? "))
    #Add information to a dictionary called employees
    em_list = [position, em_department, salary]
    employees[name] = em_list
    #Add dictionary to global dictionary of all employees
    em_global["Employee"] = employees
```

Comment: Can you share the dictionary you're getting now and the dictionary you'd like to get?

Comment: You don't need to convert the result of `input()` to a `string`...

Comment: {'richard': ['student', 'sales', 100000.0], 'henry': ['student', 'operations', 200000.0]}

Comment: But instead, I need each employee (i.e. richard and henry) to be stored in separate dictionaries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the employee's details in its own `dictionary` to the `global dictionary` - `em_global`.

So if we have the following modified `code`:

```
em_global = {}

def add_emp():
    #Ask the user to add an employee
    print("Enter the employee's information:\n")

    #Input first and last name
    name = input("What is the employee's name? ").lower()
    #Input employee position
    position = input("What is their position? ").lower()
    #Input employee department
    em_department = input("What is their department? ").lower()
    #Input employee salary
    salary = float(input("What is their salary? "))

    #create local employee dictionary
    em_dict = {'position': position,
               'em_department': em_department,
               'salary': salary}

    #Add dictionary to global dictionary of all employees
    em_global[name] = em_dict

add_emp()
```

And then if we run that and I enter the following information:

```
Enter the employee's information:

What is the employee's name? bob
What is their position? manager
What is their department? coding
What is their salary? 100.99
```

Then the `em_global` `dictionary` now becomes:

```
{'bob': {'position': 'manager', 'salary': 100.99, 'em_department': 'coding'}}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the code it seems like you already have a dictionary called employees, and another dictionary em_global. Currently you are constructing a list with employee details , you can change that to create a dict. Then you can add that to em_global["Employee"] which will be a list of dictionaries . Will it work for you?

```
  em_global={}
  em_global["Employee"] = []
  def add_emp():
    #Ask the user to add an employee
    print("Enter the employee's information:\n")
    #Input first and last name
    name = input("What is the employee's name? ").lower()
    #Input employee position
    position = input("What is their position? ").lower()
    #Input employee department
    em_department = input("What is their department? ").lower()
    #Input employee salary
    salary = float(input("What is their salary? "))
    #Add information to a dictionary called employees
    em_list={'name':name,'position':position, 'department':em_department, 'salary':salary}
    # employees[name] = em_list
    #Add dictionary to global dictionary of all employees
    em_global["Employee"].append(em_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using standard input to enter employee data, you could save the data in a json file and import this in python which is the most efficient way. For example create a json file like this:

```
{'employee1': {'em_department': 'dept1', 'position': 'pos1', 'salary': 19999}, 'employee2': {'em_department': 'dept2', 'position': 'pos2', 'salary': 29999}}
```

Then import this file in python:

```
import json
FP = open('filename')
em_global = json.load(FP)
```

Now you have a global dictionary em_global where each employee in turn is a dictionary with department, position and salary.
For example to access employee2's salary, you do

```
em_global['employee2']['salary']
```